# How do duplicate answers (auto) works?

Tags: discussion

While [reviewing the flags in Tools tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged), I came across a post with `duplicate answers (auto)`.

[image]

All three answer([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851108/android-app-wont-start-up/19851131#19851131), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828540/no-class-deffound-error-android/19828752#19828752), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833031/android-java-class-not-found-exception/19833087#19833087)) are very similar posted by same user.

I'm interested in knowing how this works.  Does this work for copied answers of different users?  Is something that can be be shared to us on how it works or detected?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a script that runs periodically, and see's whether there are any posts which are the same as another, posted by the same user, maybe restricted to within a time range... if there are, then it flags them...

Comment: Not sure of you will get an answer or not here.  Details of the various algorithms are often not disclosed to prevent gaming.  An answer here, while interesting, will give someone enough info to evade the auto flag algorithm.